# QWidget resize signal?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to take an action when a widget was resized.

Is there a way to catch that without installing an event filter on that widget (and, obviously, without subclassing it)? AFAIK, QWidget does not have a `resized` signal.

Comment: No, you cannot. The bset way is: Create your own QWidget that emits Resized in resizeEvent(), then promote your widgets to it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have any other QObject that can have strict relation to that QWidget you may use `QObject::installEventFilter(QObject * filter)` and overload `bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *)`. See more at [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Answer (score 29):

You can derive from `widget` class and reimplement `resizeEvent` event

Comment: note that warwaruk wrote "and, obviously, without subclassing it"

Comment: @KamilKlimek, ... after I posted the answer :)

Comment: I will not remove the answer, I think it could be useful for someone, who could search this question

Comment: I didn't tell anything about removing your answer

Answer (score 10):

In case you are using Python with PyQt4, you can set `widget.resizeEvent` to your function without sublclassing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def onResize(event):
    print event

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtGui.QPushButton('Test')
    widget.resizeEvent = onResize
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This prevents the base class implementation of resizeEvent from running.  It might be doing something important.  And with the monkey-patch solution, you'd have to keep a reference to the original method as a separate variable.  Messy.

Comment: @Chris The docs say that by the time resizeEvent is called the widget already has its new geometry so if you don't have anything else to do on the main widget you can just override the function. I use this technique to resize the contents of a QScrollArea.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, it looks like a hack, but I use this:

```
    some_widget.resizeEvent = (lambda old_method: (lambda event: (self._on_resized(event), old_method(event))[-1]))(some_widget.resizeEvent)
```

Comment: So much for Python being designed for legibility. However, +1 for retaining the super implementation.

Comment: Thank you, Spencer! Every answer here forgets to re-invoke a previous callback after doing his stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This is a couple of years too late, but I was working on a transparent overlay widget that would completely cover the parent. You can not do what you want without subclassing, but you can restrict the subclassing to an instance as @reclosedev suggests, meaning that you don't have to actually create a subclass.

I wrote the following snippet (which works in PyQt4) for following the size of any widget that the widget is added to:

```
class TransparentOverlay(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self._updateParent(self.parentWidget())

    def setParent(self, parent, *args):
        prevParent = self.parentWidget()
        super().setParent(parent, *args)
        self._updateParent(parent, prevParent)

    def unsetParent(self, parent=None):
        if parent is None:
            parent = self.parentWidget()
        if parent is not None and hasattr(parent.resizeEvent, '_original'):
            parent.resizeEvent = parent.resizeEvent._original

    def _updateParent(self, parent, prevParent=None):
        if parent is not prevParent:
            self.unsetParent(prevParent)
            if parent is not None:
                original = parent.resizeEvent
                def resizeEventWrapper(event):
                    original(event)
                    self.resize(event.size())
                resizeEventWrapper._original = original
                parent.resizeEvent = resizeEventWrapper
                self.resize(parent.size())
```

This code uses a couple of neat tricks that are possible with Python:

- The original method is stashed in the `_original` attribute of the new one. This is possible because functions are objects.
- The new method truly subclasses any `QWidget` *instance*, meaning that you do not have to create an actual subclass. Each parent instance will effectively become an instance of a subclass by virtue of the tacked on method.

If you need a one-time thing, all of the code for removing the subclassed `resizeEvent` method and replacing it with the original can be trashed. In that case, the solution is basically a fancier version of @reclosedev's solution, but with @Chris's comments about preserving the original addressed.

The only caveat with this code is that it does not support GL widgets correctly, so for example the overlay can not always be added to the viewport of a `QGraphicsView`. It can, however, be added to the `QGraphicsView` itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `resizeEvent`  by

```
def resizeEvent(self, newSize):
    #do code here
```