# How to listen to a widget resizeEvent without subclassing / using a filter?

Tags: c++, qt

When I try `widget->resizeEvent =`

I get this error:

[image]

And when I try to listen to the `resizeEvent` using a lambda:

```cpp
connect(widget, &QWidget::resizeEvent, [](QResizeEvent *event) {  });
```

`'QWidget::resizeEvent': cannot access protected member declared in class 'QWidget'`

Based on answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044628/19804847), I tried the above things, where they override the `resizeEvent` from outside the class.

This is not possible anymore?

The unique options to listen to the `resizeEvent` is adding filter or subclassing?

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing and event filters are the only options you have in Qt5, Qt6.
The trick you refer to is Python-only and Qt4. Events are also not signals, so you cannot connect them.

Sadly, the answer to your question simply is: you can't.